# CPanel - replace all references in user account of domainA with domainB

Tags: apache-http-server, php, cpanel

Trying to solve an easy case for when a user's domain name expired (and got stolen by squatter wanting a ransom!), for a global replacement of any text in that user's cpanel folder of the old expired domainA with domainB... Basically, global web find and replace.

domainA: myawesomedomain.com (got stolen!)

domainB: myawesomedomain.me (or another replacer that hasn't been taken)

This is in cases where there may be various different kinds of links from php includes to a hrefs and such.

I'm not sure whether an apache-level or php-global script would be more fitting, but open to suggestions of any sort. Thanks!

Comment: It might help if you listed examples of these references.. it may be that one reference is so different from another that the replacement for some references would/should be done very differently to the replacements of others. As for the content of their website, that's probably best for them to change 'cos they might not like how you change it.. even if it is just a find/replace. They might be able to get old website content from archive.org

Comment: okay added an example.

Comment: it actually isn't possible to archive.org it due to a lot of hybrid php scripts using full URLs include/requires

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect all trafic from old-domain to new-domain from .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)old-domain\.example$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://new-domain.example%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

and then you have to download the data base (an `.sql` file) and replace with and editor all occurences (for images and links in the site) and reupload to the server.

Comment: i don't have access to the old domain anymore. It got stolen by a squatter :-(